# How to add background color in parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is original image I want result to like this:

[image]

My code pen like:

```css
ul.ul_menu_parent li:hover {
  color: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid header">

 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
     <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class='text-right'>
        <span class="module_top"> <b class="phone">+ 84 862 890 890</b></span>
        <span class="module_top"><a href="#" class="register_login">Login </a> / <a href="#" class="register_login">Register </a></span>
        </div>
        
       <nav  class="navbar navbar-default nav_parent" role="navigation">
         <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
         </div>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav ul_menu_parent">
             <li style="margin-top: -5px"><a  href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
             <li><a  href="gioithieu.html">INTRO</a></li>
           </ul>
         </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It only hovers like this:

[image]

You can see the color green I only hover the awesome icon element; I can't hover to image show in parent div.

Comment: I think what you want is a *CSS Sprite Image* as using *font-awesome* wont give you result like that.

Comment: No, icon not important. I only need background colour with height larger.

Answer (score 2):

Your css needs to add like this:

```
ul.ul_menu_parent li:hover i {
 color: orange;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bug. But I want to when user hovers item in navbar; it will show image background instead of the only background in `<ul.ul_menu_parent li:hover i>`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to background color change on hover. use this css code:

```
ul.ul_menu_parent li:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
  float:left; 
  display:block;
}
```

you need to remove margin-top:-5px in li.

Comment: When I hover into item in menu, it still not working. I need like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WfbrT.png

Answer (score 1):

I added your code in jsfiddle please check this :

```
 <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/balanuidev/vtdtvkn1/">DEMO</a>
```